# insert data order by from another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

```
    I have 2 table first is master table second is transaction table.i want to insert data from second table into temp table .
```

I need to insert a table data from another table. I trying to write this sql code. But this order by option is not working while inserting the data
 insert data from table in order of grant table .but i think it insert fist then order.

```
    here is my table syntax.


    Create table tabl_master
    (DESC_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,  
      SUM_DESCRIPTION nvarchar(500) 
      )

    Create table tabl1
    (PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,  
      RFP_ID int, 
      DESC_ID int , 
      TOTAL_BUDGET decimal(18,2) 
      )


      insert into tabl_master values('1.1 Salaries-Program management staff')
      insert into tabl_master values('1.2 Salaries-Field staff, outreach workers, medical staff and other service providers')
      insert into tabl_master values('1.3 Other HR Costs')
      insert into tabl_master values('1.4 Salaries-Finance and Administration Staff')
      insert into tabl_master values('2.2 Technical Assistance related per diems/transport/other costs')
    insert into tabl_master values('2.3  Assistance related per diems/transport/other costs')

      insert into tabl1 values(101,1,2500)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,2,7500)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,3,3500)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,4,0)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,5,0)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,6,0)
    insert into tabl1 values(101,7,0)



    DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
    (
      srnum int, 
      PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID int,
      SUM_DESCRIPTION nvarchar(550),
      RFP_ID int,
      DESC_ID int,
      GRAND_TOTAL decimal(18,3)
    )
    insert  into @ProductTotals


    SELECT   row_number() over (order by (select NULL))as srnum,               
    PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID,BS.SUM_DESCRIPTION,  
      RFP_ID, PB.DESC_ID, TOTAL_BUDGET             
     FROM tabl1 PB                
      INNER JOIN tabl_master BS ON PB.DESC_ID=BS.DESC_ID               

      ORDER BY TOTAL_BUDGET  desc
       select * from @ProductTotals  

Result is coming as
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DErp.png)

And i am expecting result as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK2iw.png)

Comment: You are sorting your result by `ORDER BY TOTAL_BUDGET  desc`.

Comment: Exactly what you want to say .i am not getting.

Comment: The order of insertion is irrelevant! You need to add `order by` to your select statement.

Comment: I did it even i am not getting appropriate answer please help

Comment: You need to update your question and show me what you did.. Remember, only you know what is not working and what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
    (
      srnum int, 
      PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID int,
      SUM_DESCRIPTION nvarchar(550),
      RFP_ID int,
      DESC_ID int,
      GRAND_TOTAL decimal(18,3)
    )
    insert  into @ProductTotals

SELECT   row_number() over (order by (select NULL))as srnum,
    PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID,SUM_DESCRIPTION,
      RFP_ID, DESC_ID, TOTAL_BUDGET  from(
    SELECT
    PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID,BS.SUM_DESCRIPTION,
      RFP_ID, PB.DESC_ID, TOTAL_BUDGET
     FROM tabl1 PB
      INNER JOIN tabl_master BS ON PB.DESC_ID=BS.DESC_ID
         where    TOTAL_BUDGET <> 0 
         union all

select PROGRESS_REPORT_BUDGETID,BS.SUM_DESCRIPTION,
      RFP_ID, PB.DESC_ID, TOTAL_BUDGET
     FROM tabl1 PB
      INNER JOIN tabl_master BS ON PB.DESC_ID=BS.DESC_ID
         where    TOTAL_BUDGET = 0 
         ) A

```
   select * from @ProductTotals
```

and my expected answer will be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc0KR.png)